# PhantomJS click action not working on span when trying to login to Office365

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, office365

I am trying to automate office365 operation, and try to login using phantomjs. I use sendEvent to send click to the span UI item (which happens to be the fake submit button). I use render to capture the screen-shot after sending the click event, and it seems the button is selected (greyed out) but never receives the click event.

I have a similar problem when trying to "click" this button with Selenium.

Has anyone ever successfully automated the office365 login? I guess this has something to do with the way the web page is structured. (There is another layer of javascript that receives the click event then redirect the user to the app page).

Is there any other tool that is better fit for such task? (I tried twill as well, and have no luck.)

Comment: You should include the necessary markup of the login form and check which of the elements have any click handlers.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with logging into another Microsoft site. If I test w/ protractor and chromedriver, I can see the button "grey" out, but it doesn't work.  I can click it with the mouse and everything is fine.  If you figure out a solution to this, PLEASE let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Selenium project that logs into Office365, but I've also had a lot of issues with being able to do it consistently. The CSS selector I'm using for the Sign In button is #cred_sign_in_button. If you look at the source, that is a span that has the click handler.

```
<span id="cred_sign_in_button" tabindex="11" **onclick="Post.SubmitCreds()**;return false;" class="button normaltext cred_sign_in_button refresh_domain_state" role="button" style="opacity: 1;">Sign in</span>
```

I've found that clicking on the button once doesn't work most of the time. I assume that's due to the animation happens when you hover over the button. What finally ended up working for me was to click, wait 250ms and click again.